# Splitting a string without a delimeter in c

Tags: c, string

I want to trim this string below (which is a log.txt file) into the substring below. 
Since there are no delimeters, I can't use `strtok()`.
So how could I do it? 
Log file's contents:

```
[INFO][2019-10-2323:21:45.638]{"cmd":"set","objects":[{"type":"switch","data":["zwave-dc53:4-1"],"execution":{"command":"OnOff","params":{"on":true}}}],"raw":"DC530401010001","reqid": "0001"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:22:11.936]{"cmd":"status","objects":[{"bridge_key":"zwave","data":[{"hash":"zwave-dc53:8-0","states":{"OnOff":{"on":false}}}],"type":"switch"}],"raw":"DC53010401000000","reqid": "0001"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:22:29.232]{"cmd":"set","objects":[{"type":"switch","data":["zwave-dc53:4-1"],"execution":{"command":"OnOff","params":{"on":true}}}],"raw":"DC530401010001","reqid": "0002"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:22:29.256]{"cmd":"status","objects":[{"bridge_key":"zwave","data":[{"hash":"zwave-dc53:8-0","states":{"OnOff":{"on":false}}}],"type":"switch"}],"raw":"DC53010401000000","reqid": "0002"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:22:33.192]{"cmd":"set","objects":[{"type":"switch","data":["zwave-dc53:4-1"],"execution":{"command":"OnOff","params":{"on":true}}}],"raw":"DC530401010001","reqid": "0003}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:22:48.075]{"cmd":"status","objects":[{"bridge_key":"zwave","data":[{"hash":"zwave-dc53:8-0","states":{"OnOff":{"on":false}}}],"type":"switch"}],"raw":"DC53010401000000","reqid": "0003"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:22:48.098]{"cmd":"set","objects":[{"type":"switch","data":["zwave-dc53:4-1"],"execution":{"command":"OnOff","params":{"on":true}}}],"raw":"DC530401010001","reqid": "0004"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:22:52.034]{"cmd":"status","objects":[{"bridge_key":"zwave","data":[{"hash":"zwave-dc53:8-0","states":{"OnOff":{"on":false}}}],"type":"switch"}],"raw":"DC53010401000000","reqid": "0004"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:25:58.509]{"cmd":"set","objects":[{"type":"switch","data":["zwave-dc53:4-1"],"execution":{"command":"OnOff","params":{"on":true}}}],"raw":"DC530401010001","reqid": "0005"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:26:42.425]{"cmd":"status","objects":[{"bridge_key":"zwave","data":[{"hash":"zwave-dc53:8-0","states":{"OnOff":{"on":false}}}],"type":"switch"}],"raw":"DC53010401000000","reqid": "0005"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:27:15.467]{"cmd":"set","objects":[{"type":"switch","data":["zwave-dc53:4-1"],"execution":{"command":"OnOff","params":{"on":true}}}],"raw":"DC530401010001","reqid": "0006"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:27:42.030]{"cmd":"status","objects":[{"bridge_key":"zwave","data":[{"hash":"zwave-dc53:8-0","states":{"OnOff":{"on":false}}}],"type":"switch"}],"raw":"DC53010401000000","reqid": "0006"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:32:45.088]{"cmd":"set","objects":[{"type":"switch","data":["zwave-ffa2:4-1"],"execution":{"command":"OnOff","params":{"on":true}}}],"raw":"FFA20401010001","reqid": "0033"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:33:11.934]{"cmd":"status","objects":[{"bridge_key":"zwave","data":[{"hash":"zwave-ffa2:8-0","states":{"OnOff":{"on":false}}}],"type":"switch"}],"raw":"FFA2010401000000","reqid": "0007"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:36:39.262]{"cmd":"set","objects":[{"type":"switch","data":["zwave-ffa2:4-1"],"execution":{"command":"OnOff","params":{"on":true}}}],"raw":"FFA20401010001","reqid": "0008"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:36:39.267]{"cmd":"status","objects":[{"bridge_key":"zwave","data":[{"hash":"zwave-ffa2:8-0","states":{"OnOff":{"on":false}}}],"type":"switch"}],"raw":"FFA2010401000000","reqid": "0008"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:36:39.267]{"cmd":"set","objects":[{"type":"switch","data":["zwave-ffa2:4-1"],"execution":{"command":"OnOff","params":{"on":true}}}],"raw":"FFA20401010001","reqid": "0022"}
[INFO][2019-10-2323:36:39.332]{"cmd":"status","objects":[{"bridge_key":"zwave","data":[{"hash":"zwave-ffa2:8-0","states":{"OnOff":{"on":false}}}],"type":"switch"}],"raw":"FFA2010401000000","reqid": "0009"}
```

The substring I want to find is the raw data's value, for example: `FFA2010401000000`

Comment: look for the positions of `,"raw":"` strings with `strstr` ? use a proper json parser ?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in C? I'd use Python or something.

Comment: You might find [regular expression](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regular-expressions-in-c/) useful in this scenario.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre From a quick inspection, the posted data doesn't appear to me to be fully proper JSON, so a JSON parser would likely gag on it without a lot of tweaking.

Comment: Where does the log come from?

Comment: What do you mean by "no delimiters"?  The nil character marking end of string is an internal representation.   For example fgets() reads characters into a buffer until after it detects a newline, then appends a `\0` to make a string out of it.  Fputs() writes characters from a string, but stops before writing the '\0`.

Comment: If you don't need it to be in C, `sed 's/.*raw":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/'`

Answer (score 1):

You might find [regular expression](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regular-expressions-in-c/) useful in this scenario. Specifically [regexec](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regexec) seems appropriate here.

```
int regexec(const regex_t *preg, const char *string, size_t nmatch,
            regmatch_t pmatch[], int eflags);
```

Or a proper json parser. Checkout the [c library section](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) on the json format description website.

Answer (score 1):

This should work to extract the raw data, assuming it's hex-encoded data (error checking, memory freeing, and proper headers are omitted for clarity):

```
#define RAW_STR ",\"raw\":\""

FILE *logfile = fopen( filename, "rb" );

char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;

for ( ;; )
{
    ssize_t bytesRead = getline( &line, &len, logfile );
    if ( bytesRead == -1 )
    {
        break;
    }

    char *rawData = strstr( line, RAW_STR );
    if ( !raw )
    {
        continue;
    }

    // jump over the "raw":" string to the  actual value
    rawData += strlen( RAW_STR );

    // assume the data is hex
    unsigned long long value = strtoull( rawData, NULL, 16 );

    ...
}
```

This simple method depends on the log file being consistently formatted.  If the log file doesn't always have the `RAW_STR` in that **exact** format, it won't work.

I've also assumed you're running on a POSIX system and have access to `getline()`.